405 from Google Tag Manager, when firing from Apps Script
I've tried to add ad conversion tracking to a Google Form, but get a 405 HTTP error when I try to run the script from Google Tag Manager. 405 means "Method not allowed", but I have hard time imagining, that POST is forbidden. What else could be wrong?
Why would I try to add ad conversion tracking? The main conversion that I want to track is when people fill out a Google Form. But tracking it seems not directly possible.

Don't have access to backend, to put in code
The URL of the landing page, after filling out, has the same URL
A redirect to another page afterwards isn't possible.

The workaround:

Link a Google Sheet to the form
Add AppsScript
In AppsScript add a trigger, that fires, when a new entry is entered

The script looks the following:
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  try {
    
    var containerId = 'GTM-XXXXXX'; 

    // Create a dataLayer object with the event name
    var dataLayer = [{
      'event': 'formSubmission', 
      'formName': 'My Form Name' 
    }];

    // Send the dataLayer to GTM
    sendGtmData(containerId, dataLayer);

    // Log successful execution
    Logger.log('GTM data sent successfully.');

  } catch (error) {
    // Log the error for debugging
    Logger.log('Error sending GTM data: ' + error); 

    MailApp.sendEmail('to@me.com', 'GTM Data Send Error', 'An error occurred: ' + error); 
  }
}


// Function to send data to GTM (requires GTM API)
function sendGtmData(containerId, dataLayer) {
  try {
  
    if (PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('hasInstalledGTM') !== 'true') {
      var url = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + containerId;
      UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('hasInstalledGTM', 'true');
    }

    // Send the dataLayer to GTM
    var payload = {
      'dataLayer': dataLayer
    };
    var options = {
      'method': 'post',
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'payload': JSON.stringify(payload)
    };
    UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + containerId + '&l=dataLayer', options);

  } catch (error) {
    // Log the error within this function
    Logger.log('Error sending data to GTM: ' + error); 
    throw error; // Re-throw the error to be caught by the outer try-catch block
  }
}

The error I get is:
Error sending data to GTM: Exception: Request failed for https://www.googletagmanager.com returned code 405. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html>

Maybe there is a better way to use GTM in AppsScript?
Thanks!

I am not quite sure what you want to achieve here.
gtm.js can only be loaded in a website and wait for trigger.
The usual process is install GTM in a website or the form you mentioned.
onFormSubmit : push a datalayer into the website. Not into GTM.
GTM will only monitor the datalayer array. Not taking data from datalayer. We can not post or send data into GTM. datalayer is quite like a information board and GTM will only look at it.

I'll try explaining better the goal. I use Google Ads. But the main conversion, that I want to track, where the actual value is created, is when people fill out a Google Form. What I can track, is a click on that link. But if they have clicked, they haven't filled out the form yet. The Google Form is on another URL and the page after filling out the form successfully is on the same URL.
What I tried is a workaround to make the filling out of a GF trackable. By linking it to a Sheet, in which I run AppsScript and send the conversion ID/label. Can I use GTM directly in AppsScript? A library?

Updated the original question with the motivation.

Afraid of not. You might need to use some offline import conversion feature in Google Ads.
https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/2998031?hl=en&ref_topic=7280668&sjid=16201125420698300111-AP
